Keyboard Avoidance Issue in SwiftUI Sheet View
I am working on a chat view and trying to override keyboard avoidance. As it is, when I tap on the TextField to enter a comment, the entire view gets pushed upward, instead of just the textfield itself with the keyboard popping up below it. The chat view is presented via .sheet with a presentationDetent of 0.8.
I have tried using .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom) after embedding the view in a GeometryReader and a ZStack but to no avail. I've also tried separating the components into different views.
Here is the relevant code:
struct TakesChatView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: TakeCommentViewModel
    @FocusState var focus: Bool
    @State private var selectedMedia: [PhotosPickerItem] = []
    @State private var selectedImageData: [Data] = []
    @State private var selectedGIFData: [Data] = []
    @State private var selectedVideoData: [Data] = []
    
    var textFieldNotEmpty: Bool {
        !viewModel.textToPost.isEmpty ||
        !selectedImageData.isEmpty ||
        !selectedGIFData.isEmpty ||
        !selectedVideoData.isEmpty
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            GeometryReader { _ in
                VStack {
                    contentView
                    commentTextField
                        .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                }
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)
        .navigationTitle(viewModel.take.title)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .background(Color.containerBackground)
        .onChange(of: viewModel.focus) { focus in
            self.focus = focus
        }
        .onChange(of: selectedMedia) { _ in
            loadMedia()
        }
    }
    
    var contentView: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer().frame(height: 105)
            ScrollViewReader { scroll in
                ScrollView(showsIndicators: true) {
                    ForEach(viewModel.comments, id: \.self) { comment in
                        TakeCommentView(
                            comment: comment,
                            viewModel: self.viewModel
                        )
                        .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                        .id(comment.documentID)
                    }
                    .onChange(of: viewModel.commentAdded) { id in
                        scroll.scrollTo(id, anchor: .bottom)
                        viewModel.commentAdded = nil
                    }
                }
                .scrollDismissesKeyboard(.immediately)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension TakesChatView {
    @ViewBuilder
    var commentTextField: some View {
        VStack {       
            HStack {
                TextField("Type your comment", text: $viewModel.textToPost, axis: .vertical)
                    .keyboardType(.twitter)
                    .padding([.leading, .vertical], 6)
                    .focused($focus)
                
                PhotosPicker(selection: $selectedMedia, matching: .any(of: [.images, .videos]), photoLibrary: .shared()) {
                    ComposeType.media.image
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                }
                .onAppear {
                    selectedMedia.removeAll()
                    selectedImageData.removeAll()
                    selectedGIFData.removeAll()
                    selectedVideoData.removeAll()
                }
                
                postButton
            }
            .border(.lightGray, width: 1, cornerRadius: 10)
            .padding([.bottom, .horizontal], 10)
        }
    }
}

What should I do in order to have the keyboard avoidance be removed so that when I tap on the TextField, it'll be like Instagram's comment section for example where the textfield moves up with the keyboard popping up below it, but the view itself that's displaying the comments isn't shifted upward entirely?
Edit: I have made reproducible code to represent my issue. The code is found below:
struct ButtonView: View {
    @State private var showChat: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                showChat.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Tap Me!")
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showChat, content: {
            ContentView(viewModel: ContentViewViewModel())
                .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.8)])
                .presentationDragIndicator(.hidden)
                .overlay(
                    VStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2)
                            .fill(Color.gray)
                            .frame(width: 40, height: 5)
                            .padding(.top, 15)
                            .opacity(0.8)
                        Label("Chat", systemImage: "message.badge")
                            .lineLimit(nil)
                            .padding(.top, 5)
                            .padding([.leading, .trailing], 16)
                        Divider()
                            .padding(.top, 5)
                            .padding([.leading, .trailing], 16)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .top)
                )
        })
    }
}

struct UserMockComments: Identifiable {
    let userName: String
    var comment: String
    var id = UUID().uuidString
}

class ContentViewViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var mock = [UserMockComments]()
    @Published var text: String = ""
    
    init() {
        fetchData()
    }
    
    func fetchData() {
        let mockComments: [UserMockComments] = [
            .init(userName: "OHeg12", comment: "Hello World!"),
            .init(userName: "OHeg12", comment: "Hello World!"),
            .init(userName: "OHeg12", comment: "Hello World!"),
            .init(userName: "OHeg12", comment: "Hello World!"),
            .init(userName: "OHeg12", comment: "Hello World!"),
            .init(userName: "OHeg12", comment: "Hello World!"),
            .init(userName: "OHeg12", comment: "Hello World!"),
            .init(userName: "OHeg12", comment: "Hello World!"),
            .init(userName: "OHeg12", comment: "Hello World!"),
            .init(userName: "OHeg12", comment: "Hello World!"),
            .init(userName: "OHeg12", comment: "Hello World!"),
            .init(userName: "OHeg12", comment: "Hello World!")
        ]
        
        self.mock = mockComments
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ContentViewViewModel()
    @FocusState var focus: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            GeometryReader { _ in
                VStack {
                    comments
                    commentTextField
                        .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                }
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)
    }
    
    var comments: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer().frame(height: 105)
            ScrollViewReader { scroll in
                ScrollView(showsIndicators: true) {
                    ForEach(viewModel.mock) { mockComments in
                        Text(mockComments.userName)
                        Text(mockComments.comment)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                            .id(mockComments.id)
                    }
                }
                .scrollDismissesKeyboard(.immediately)
            }
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    var commentTextField: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                TextField("Type your comment", text: $viewModel.text, axis: .vertical)
                    .keyboardType(.twitter)
                    .padding([.leading, .vertical], 6)
                    .focused($focus)
            }
            .padding([.bottom, .horizontal], 10)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ContentViewViewModel()
    return ContentView(viewModel: viewModel)
}

ButtonView is the main view of the app and tapping on the button loads up the chat view with the issue I'm having.

Your code is not reproducible, so I cannot test. Look into placing the textfield into a .safeAreaInset:
.safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {    TextField("Chat", text: $chat)     .padding()   }

I still get the same issue where the keyboard would shift the entire view upwards

If you won't provide some reproducible code, not much I can do.

@AndreiG. I have provided reproducible code in my question for you to look over.

Try the code below as your ContentView body:
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            GeometryReader { _ in
                VStack {
                    comments
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center) //center the comments
                    // commentTextField
                        // .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                }
            }
        }
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
            commentTextField
                .padding(.top,5)
                .background(.white)
        }
        // .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)
    }


When I add it to the reproducible code, it works. But when I add it to my actual project's code, it still shifts the view upward instead of just having the commentTextField view slide up without affecting the comments view and for some reason a extra toolbar with the Done button appears above the keyboard and below the textfield while it doesn't show in my reproducible code.

As in my example above, make sure you comment out any .ignoreSafeArea modifiers. The Done button could come from a .toolbar modifier that adds a button in the keyboard toolbar.

I have commented out all .ignoreSafeArea modifiers. The issue still stands. I can handle having the extra toolbar but the main issue is that the view still gets pushed upwards by the keyboard. Is it something to do with TakeCommentView as that displays the user comments

If the issue is not present in the reproducible code you provided, I can't really say, as I can't really troubleshoot it.
